# Attempting to connect to SQL Server through Crystal Reports

Tags: sql-server, crystal-reports

I am attempting to connect Crystal reports to a SQL Server database. Here is what I have done so far.

`File > Log On or Off Server`

`Create New Connection > OLE DB (ADO)`

Under provider I selected `Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server` and click next.

I select the server from the drop down list and put in the username and password for the local admin account. I am able to remote to the server using this account. For the database field I have tried to enter the database name and the path to the .mdf for this database. I get the same error either way.

```
Login failed.
Details: ADO Error Code: 0x80040e4d
Source: Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server
Description: Login failed for user 'server\admin'.
SQL State: 42000
Native Error: 18456 [Database Vendor Code: 18456 ]
```

Crystal Reports version: 14.0.4.738 RTM
SQL Server 2012

I did find some similar error messages through google, but the situations were different, so it was not helpful.

Comment: Please use SQL native client for MSSQL 2012. Download drive from here https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29065

Comment: What will this do for me? Do I need to install it on my machine or the server?

Comment: Are you using windows authentication? Why does the login id has a domain like prefix?

Comment: I am using windows authentication. The ID has the prefix because it is a local account rather than a domain account. I have tried both with and without the prefix and got the same error.

Comment: Are you trying to remotely connect to a LocalDB database (*.mdf) from one maching to another machine? I don't think that what it's designed for.

Comment: Its a new driver for the 2012 sql server.  you do not have to use old Microsoft OLE DB Provider.

Comment: @jjj I didn't think so, which is why I tried the DB name first, but that did not work, so I tried putting the path to the file in the database field.

Comment: @Hiten004 So, that should show up under `Create New Connection` after I install it?

Comment: `SQL Server Native Client` should show up in the list of `OLE DB (ADO)` providers. If the .mdf file was already attached to a LocalDB instance, you'd be able to connect to it by setting the server to something like `(localdb)\v11.0` and checking the `Integrated Security` box, but that's only from the same computer as the file (usually).

Comment: @jjj I already have that installed and that is what I was trying to use. The computer that I am using crystal on is not the same computer that is the SQL server.

Comment: Do you have CONNECT permissions for the server\admin? I don't think your issue is with the driver. It has most likely to do with the permissions/authorization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you get a "Database Vendor Code" error, this means that the error code was passed back from the database.  So, we know this is a SQL Server error, not a Crystal error.

I found this post quite interesting, so I started researching what other people had to say regarding this subject matter. I stumbled upon this blog which seems to be a few years old. But, this talks about the Native Error: 18456 (which is the exact error code you are getting). So, I am hoping that if you try to create a udf file like the article suggests. You might end up getting something out of it. Here is the link to the article:

[Crystal Reports Generating SQL Server Error 18456 Severity 8 Error Logs](http://jwcooney.com/2011/10/03/crystal-reports-generating-sql-server-error-18456-severity-8-error-logs/)

Answer (score 0):

You may have permissions to remote to the Windows server , but the user should be added also to the SQLServer

Comment: The user is already added to the SQL server. I can log in to SQL Server Management Studio with that account using windows auth.